# Is ChannelId.asShortText() unique among thousands of connections in netty 4?

Tags: java, sockets, netty

In netty (netty 4.1) each connection (channel) is identified by `ChannelId`:

```
public interface ChannelId extends Serializable, Comparable<ChannelId> {
    /**
     * Returns the short but globally non-unique string representation of the {@link ChannelId}.
     */
    String asShortText();

    /**
     * Returns the long yet globally unique string representation of the {@link ChannelId}.
     */
    String asLongText();
}
```

As javadoc says, the `asShorText` is globally non-unique. But it is implemented as:

```
@Override
public String asShortText() {
    String shortValue = this.shortValue;
    if (shortValue == null) {
        this.shortValue = shortValue = ByteBufUtil.hexDump(
                data, MACHINE_ID_LEN + PROCESS_ID_LEN + SEQUENCE_LEN + TIMESTAMP_LEN, RANDOM_LEN);
    }
    return shortValue;
}
```

Suppose we have only fifty thousands of TCP connections on single server instance, does the return value of `asShortText` provide sufficient information to to identify each channel, which means it can be treated as unique for small number of connections on same server?